# How to conver excel contents into python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ordereddictionary

I have an excel spreadsheet with 1st column = IP subnet & the 2nd column = Firewall name, trying to use this data to create a dictionary.
e.g. excel format -

10.1.1.0/24           ASA_01

10.2.2.0/24           ASA_02

10.3.3.0/24           ASA_03

I am using pandas module to achieve this, however, the dictionary format doesn't look correct.

The required output should be something like this -
{'10.1.1.0/24' : 'ASA_01', '10.2.2.0/24': 'ASA_02', '10.3.3.0/24': 'ASA_03'}

However, the output I am getting is this -
{'ASA_01': {'10.2.2.0/24': 'ASA_02', '10.3.3.0/24': 'ASA_03'}}

Here is the code that I am using-

fw = pandas.read_excel(host_file, index_col=0).to_dict()

print(fw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no first row with columns names, so add parameter `header=None` and then select second column called `1` for `Series`:

```
fw = pandas.read_excel(host_file, index_col=0, header=None)[1].to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
fw = pandas.read_excel(host_file, index_col=0).T.to_dict()
```

T means transpose here, and it like rotating the table.